# Linq query to Datasource,InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to query a table from a simple MS Access database, local file, the query works but I can't set it to the DataSoruce:

```
 IEnumerable<DataRow> result = from row in bDSpitalDataSet.Tabel.AsEnumerable()
                     where row.Varsta >= up &&
                           row.Varsta <= down &&
                           row.CNP.StartsWith(Convert.ToString(sex))
                     select row;

        DataTable resultTable = result.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();

        tabelBindingSource.DataSource = resultTable;

        dataGridView1.Update();
```

So I get the `InvalidOperationException` at the             `DataTable resultTable = result.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();`

operation. Any idea?

Comment: what is the type of `tabelBindingSource`?

Comment: An `InvalidOperationException` has a message that often describes the underlying problem. Also, a stack trace might provide additional hints of what the problem is.

Comment: perhaps you want dataGridView1.DataSource = resultTable  ??

Comment: the tabelBindingSource is an instance of the  BindingSource class

Comment: dataGridView1.DataSource = resultTable, same exception

Comment: What is the full message of the InvalidOperationException? One possible cause for the exception is if the BindingSource detects a recursion.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll

Comment: @Daniel: then you don't get the exception at `tabelBindingSource.DataSource = resultTable` as claimed but at `CopyToDataTable` because `result` contained no rows.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter Yes, you are right, sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume[1](**edit**: now confirmed by OP) that you don't get the exception at `tabelBindingSource.DataSource = resultTable` but at `result.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>()` because the query doesn't contain any DataRows. The columns of the new `DataTable` will be derived from `DataRow.Table.Columns`, if there are no rows there are no informations.

The exception is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189(v=vs.110).aspx):

`InvalidOperationException`:

- A `DataRow` in the source sequence has a state of `Deleted`.
- **The source sequence does not contain any `DataRow` objects**.
- A `DataRow` in the source sequence is `null`.

You can use `Any` to check it before:

```
if(result.Any())
{
    DataTable resultTable = result.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
    tabelBindingSource.DataSource = resultTable;
    dataGridView1.Update();
}
```

a more efficient approach:

```
DataTable resultTable = bDSpitalDataSet.Tabel.Clone();
foreach(DataRow row in result.Rows)
    resultTable.LoadDataRow(row.ItemArray, false);
```

more efficicient because `result.Any()` needs to execute the query to determine if there's at least one row, `result.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>()` executes it a second time.

---

[1] Why i assume that you've mentioned the wrong error-line? Because of your comment:

> *An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll*

Comment: Thanks, just one question, if I don't get any result, how do I show a empty dataGrid?

Comment: @Daniel: you can assign `null` as `DataSource` of the `DataGridView` or the `BindingSource`.